# Reflection within IQueryable in .NET Core

Tags: linq, .net-core, reflection, iqueryable

I am wondering how would the below code work and what would be the performance. I am interested in line #4 basically. How will linq and property info work together?

In other words will `(int)prop.GetValue(a)` and `a.SomeId` work the same way or will the reflection need to get everything to memory before checking the value?

```
var prop = type.GetProperty("SomeId");

if (prop != null) 
{
     DbSet<T> dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
     return dbSet.Where(a => (int)prop.GetValue(a) == 1);
}
```

Comment: depending on the backing store, the context may fail to convert the expression to the underlying query syntax (eg. SQL). You could consider building an valid expression manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words will `(int)prop.GetValue(a)` and `a.SomeId` work the same way

**No.**

Depending on the backing store, the context may fail to convert that expression (`(int)prop.GetValue(a)`) to the underlying query syntax, which in most cases would be SQL.

You could consider building a valid expression manually using the property info.

For example

```
//Assuming
Type type = typeof(T);

PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("SomeId");
if (prop != null) {
    //need to build a => a.SomeId == 1

    // a =>
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "a");
    // a => a.SomeId
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, prop);
    // a => a.SomeId == 1
    BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(1));

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

    DbSet<T> dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();

    return dbSet.Where(expression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nkosi, that was the answer i needed. So, i assume, this way, EF will not have a problem generating SQL query. Is my understanding right ?

Comment: @Elnoor correct. by building the expression, EF will be able to generate the required syntax.

Comment: awesome, thanks ! Now i should be done completing my multi tenancy :)